# How to run a query and put the result into a variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am running a query from the VBA editor of Access:

```
select max(somerow) from sometable
```

I want to put the result of this query into a VBA variable. How do i do it?

Comment: What is this campaign of yours about where you ask incredibly elementary questions, most of which could be answered by a minute of Googling or delving into the Access help files? What is your point in doing this?

Comment: Umm.. isn't this question a duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837795/how-to-run-a-query-from-the-vba-editor-window-in-access/2837939#2837939

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at Access Help for DMax function.

```
Dim varSomething As Variant
varSomething = DMax("somerow", "sometable")
```

**Edit**: I realize that suggestion is not what you were looking for.  But it seems to me you may be taking the long way round to achieve something that is simple with the DMax domain function.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the Max value, you should consider using HansUps Solution.

Here is a solution using DAO:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim sqlMax As String
Dim result As Integer

sqlMax = "select max(somerow) from sometable"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlMax)

If rs.Fields.Count = 1 Then
    result = rs.Fields(0)
End If

Set rs = Nothing
```

*You will need to add a Reference to the Microsoft DAO Object library through Tools->References in the VBA Editor*

Comment: That reference will already be there for databases created in any version except 2000, unless somebody has removed it (which they shouldn't). Also, you don't even need the reference if you declare your recordset variable as type Object. The rest of it will work perfectly in that case even without the reference.